compose - Photo Picker with camera is not working
SO I am trying to pick a Photo thro camera and show it on the screen. But everytime after picking the image it looks something like this] . It's just white, there is not content inside.
I have checked the logs, and Image uri is not null, ranther it looks something like
content://com.mifos.mifosxdroid.provider/client_image/client_image1448774659534093575.png
I have already tried this method - Compose - Take Photo with camera and display result not working, but still not working
Here is what I have on compose screen.
    var selectedImageUri : Uri? by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(null) }

    val file = context.createTempImageFile()
    val imgUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        Objects.requireNonNull(context),
        "com.mifos.mifosxdroid" + ".provider",
        file
    )
    val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
        onResult = { success ->
            if (success) {
                selectedImageUri = imgUri
            }
        }
    )

Image(
    painter = if (selectedImageUri != null) rememberAsyncImagePainter(selectedImageUri) 
    else painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_dp_placeholder ),
    contentDescription = null,
modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
                    .clickable {
                        cameraLauncher.launch(imgUri)
                    }
                    .border(color = DarkGray, width = 2.dp, shape = CircleShape)
                    .size(80.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
)



This is another function
fun Context.createTempImageFile(): File {
    val imageFileName = "client_image"
    return File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName, /* prefix */
        ".png", /* suffix */
        externalCacheDir /* directory */
    )
}

This is what I have as provider_paths.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-cache-path name="client_image" path="/" />
</paths>

In the manifest
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mifos.mifosxdroid.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

Can anyone help me with this to fix the issue, I would be grateful, Thanks

"ranther it looks something like" -- that looks fine. If you look at your phone using Device File Explorer in Android Studio, do you have a photo at the location identified by file? If you do not, then your problem lies with the camera app.

I tested with an emulator as well, any idea why the photo is not showing? @CommonsWare

Let me try asking again: if you look at your phone using Device File Explorer in Android Studio, do you have a photo at the location identified by file? If you do not, then your problem lies with the camera app.

@CommonsWare I could not find any image in the file explorer.. Do you know what might be the issue?

Only use TakePicture if you do not necessarily need it to work. Camera apps are very unreliable, as there is no testing being done to ensure that they work with third-party apps using TakePicture. If you absolutely need a photo, use CameraX or another camera library and take the picture inside your own app, rather than delegating that work to some other camera app.

@CommonsWare hey, I did debug, Now it shows on the FIle Explorer, not on the screen.. Any reason why it's happening??

Rather than using the Uri, use file for rememberAsyncImagePainter(), and see if that helps.

@CommonsWare didnt work
